# Centering content & Exclusive tablet view with Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I was wondering is there anyway to get a exclusive tablet view in foundation with its grid. I want an specific grid layout for desktop [achieved], one for tablet [not achieved] and one for mobile which is done perfectly. but after it's major breakpoint at 768px there's no difference between mobile view and tablet view regarding the columns lining upon each other. If you get what I'm saying some of columns get too big in tablet view which isn't absolutely necessary. There's no necessity to show them with 12-column mobile grid.

Second issue, I downloaded the RTL version of Zurb Foundation (the problem stays when using the original copy), the "row" element which has a role similar to "container" or "wrapper" or something like that, is started from the right side (left side in original version) and it's not absolutely centered. The problem becomes more critical when we enter mobile view and using block grid. Elements are not centered.

I really appreciate your answers guys :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question you can only get the tablet only grid if you are using SASS or SCSS.

*This experimental feature is currently only available by using SASS and importing the _grid-5.scss file into your Compass project. You can also simply download the grid-5.css file, and link to it in your HTML head after your foundation.css. 
[Medium Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#medium-grid)

As for the RTL can you post a example showing how it looks in RTL and LTR so I can get a better idea of what you are seeing. Also its easier to have one question per post.